# Value of CRC changing everytime program is run

Tags: c, image, file, crc

I am writing a CLI utility in C that analyzes PNG files and outputs data about it. More specifically, it prints out the length, CRC and type values of each chunk in the PNG file. I am using the [official specification](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/iso/index-object.html) for the PNG file format and it says that each chunk has a CRC value encoded in it for data integrity.

My tool is running fine and it outputs the correct values for length and type and outputs what *appears* to be a correct value for the CRC (as in it is formatted as 4-bytes hexadecimal) - the only problem is that everytime I run this program, the value of the CRC changes. Is this normal, and if not what could be causing it?

Here is the main part of the code

```
CHUNK chunk;
BYTE buffer;
int i = 1;

while (chunk.type != 1145980233) {  // 1145980233 is a magic number that signals our program that IEND chunk 
                                        // has been reached it is just the decimal equivalent of 'IEND'
        
        printf("============\nCHUNK: %i\n", i);
        // Read LENGTH value; we have to buffer and then append to length hexdigit-by-hexdigit to account for 
        // reversals of byte-order when reading infile (im not sure why this reversal only happens here)
        for(unsigned j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
            fread(&buffer, 1, sizeof(BYTE), png);
            chunk.length = (chunk.length | buffer)<<8;  // If length is 0b4e and buffer is 67 this makes sure that length
                                                        // ends up 0b4e67 and not 0b67
        }
        chunk.length = chunk.length>>8; // Above bitshifting ends up adding an extra 00 to end of length
                                        // This gets rid of that
        printf("LENGTH: %u\n", chunk.length);

        // Read TYPE value
        fread(&chunk.type, 4, sizeof(BYTE), png);
        // Print out TYPE in chars
        printf("TYPE: ");
        printf("%c%c%c%c\n", chunk.type & 0xff, (chunk.type & 0xff00)>>8, (chunk.type & 0xff0000)>>16, (chunk.type & 0xff000000)>>24);
        
        // Allocate LENGTH bytes of memory for data
        chunk.data = calloc(chunk.length, sizeof(BYTE));
        // Populate DATA
        for(unsigned j = 0; j < chunk.length; ++j) {
            fread(&buffer, 1, sizeof(BYTE), png);
        }

        // Read CRC value
        for(unsigned j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
            fread(&chunk.crc, 1, sizeof(BYTE), png);
        }
        printf("CRC: %x\n", chunk.crc);
        printf("\n");
        i++;
    }
```

here are some preprocessor directives and global variables

```
#define BYTE uint8_t

typedef struct {
    uint32_t length;
    uint32_t type;
    uint32_t crc;
    BYTE* data;
} CHUNK;
```

here are some examples of the output I am getting

Run 1 -

```
============
CHUNK: 1
LENGTH: 13
TYPE: IHDR
CRC: 17a6a400

============
CHUNK: 2
LENGTH: 2341
TYPE: iCCP
CRC: 17a6a41e
```

Run 2 -

```
============
CHUNK: 1
LENGTH: 13
TYPE: IHDR
CRC: 35954400

============
CHUNK: 2
LENGTH: 2341
TYPE: iCCP
CRC: 3595441e
```

Run 3 -

```
============
CHUNK: 1
LENGTH: 13
TYPE: IHDR
CRC: 214b0400

============
CHUNK: 2
LENGTH: 2341
TYPE: iCCP
CRC: 214b041e
```

As you can see, the CRC values are different each time, yet within each run they are all fairly similar whereas my intuition tells me this should not be the case and the CRC value should not be changing.

Just to make sure, I also ran

```
    $ cat test.png > file1
    $ cat test.png > file2
    $ diff -s file1 file2
    Files file1 and file2 are identical
```

so accessing the file two different times doesnt change the CRC values in them, as expected.

Thanks,

Comment: `fread(&chunk.crc, 1, sizeof(BYTE), png);` Each of the 4 iterations will read a byte and overwrite the one that was previously stored at `&chunk.crc`. The other 3 bytes in `chunk.crc` remain uninitialized.

Comment: What @dxiv said about crc is also true where you read data.  You don't need a loop.  Just feed fread the number of bytes you want to read (in the case of crc it is 4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
fread(&chunk.crc, 1, sizeof(BYTE), png);
```

keeps overwriting the first byte of `chunk.crc` with the bytes read from the file. The other three bytes of `chunk.crc` are never written, and so you are seeing whatever was randomly in memory at those locations when your program started. You will note that the `00` and `1e` at the ends is consistent, since that is the one byte that is being written.

Same problem with this in your data reading loop:

```
fread(&buffer, 1, sizeof(BYTE), png);
```

An unrelated error is that you are accumulating bytes in a 32-bit integer thusly:

```
chunk.length = (chunk.length | buffer)<<8;
```

and then after the end of that loop, rolling it back down:

```
chunk.length = chunk.length>>8;
```

That will always discard the most significant byte of the length, since you push it off the top of the 32 bits, and then roll eight zero bits back down in its place. Instead you need to do it like this:

```
chunk.length = (chunk.length << 8) | buffer;
```

and then all 32 bits are retained, and you don't need to fix it at the end.

This is a bad idea:

```
fread(&chunk.type, 4, sizeof(BYTE), png);
```

because it is not portable. What you end up with in `chunk.type` depends on the endianess of the architecture it is running on. For "IHDR", you will get `0x52444849` on a little-endian machine, and `0x49484452` on a big-endian machine.